# Puppeteer - height is different in chromium browser

Tags: reactjs, node.js, puppeteer

I'm using puppeteer to generate pdf files for the user.
For that I'm rendering a react component and I'm using the setContent functionality

I'm using my code in my application (nextjs) and in puppeteer for generation.
But when I inspect the page, I see that the elements have different heights. There is no height set in my project, so it should be 'auto'.

puppeteer:

```
 const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
 const htmlString = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
                    <>
                        <div style={{ height: 500, width: 500 }}>
                            <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
                                <span>HASS1</span>
                                <span>HASS2</span>
                                <span>HASS3</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </>,
                );
                await page.setContent(htmlString);
                await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 1080 });
                await page.emulateMediaType('screen');
                await page.waitForSelector('#footer-is-loaded');
                const pdfBuffer = await page.pdf({ format: 'A4' });
...
```

my application:

```
const TestPage = props => {
    return (
        <div style={{ height: 500, width: 500 }}>
            <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
                <span>HASS1</span>
                <span>HASS2</span>
                <span>HASS3</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Here you see the different heights:

own website:

[image]

chromium test browser of puppeteer:

[image]

I am very confused. I want to show a pdf preview (before generation) on my webpage. But this way the user sees a different layout because of different heights.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try set it manually in browser using devtools - Mobile version is allowing fixed width and height for the window.

Comment: I don't understand why this could help me?
You suggest to open the puppeteer browser and then edit the height in dev tools? 
Why should that help me while generating PDF files automatically with puppeteer?

Answer (score 0):

For all people running into that issue in future:
The problem was not related to puppeteer. After some testing I found out, that my NextJS application sets (somewhere) the line-height property to 1.5 .
So I have to overwrite it at my pages with line-height: normal .
Now my preview on my nextjs page and the rendered pdf by puppeteer has the same line height.